# New tag request: RCS (Rich Communication Services)

Tags: feature-request, tags

Apparently, there is no RCS tag yet.

RCS is [Rich Communication Services](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Communication_Services) and the standard is getting more widespread use. There are only [a few questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=RCS) related to it for now (like [mine](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236737/cannot-disable-mms-link-sharing-without-creating-samsung-account), posted before I knew that was the source of my problem), but I would expect the need to rapidly grow as providers add support for the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[rich-communication-services](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rich-communication-services) and its synonym [rcs](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rcs) have been created.**

The tag has been added for questions clearly and specifically about RCS:

- [RCS Messaging Encryption](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/219503/rcs-messaging-encryption)
- [Google's Messages app says text message sent by SMS](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232098/googles-messages-app-says-text-message-sent-by-sms)

Feel free to add to other questions if it helps :)